# How to make a POST call with JSON data using curl?

Tags: json, api, curl, post

I have tried only GET calls using curl, and now I need to make a POST call. I need to give the parameters or input using JSON. How do I write this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to user header option in your command as below.
-H/--header "Content-Type: application/json"

So the full command will be like:
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"abc","password":"xyz"}' http://url/to/some/server

Comment: i tried your format Hrishikesh. It works as expected for me thanks a lot .

Comment: I tried to use the same format on Linux but I am getting "no data provided" error.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are asking how to format a curl POST request with JSON attributes.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{'json':{'key':'value'}}" http://your.domain/endpoint/here
```

[This page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) covers a lot of useful cases.

Comment: Thanks Jack and Hrishikesh your answer helped me a lot . i formed the following curl command :  curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{'json':{"Name": "web","TaskTemplate":{"ContainerSpec":{"Image": "nginx:alpine","Mounts":[{"VolumeOptions":{"DriverConfig":{}}}],"User": "33"},"LogDriver":{"Name": "json-file","Options":{"max-file": "3","max-size": "10M"}}}}}" https://<IP-Address>:2376/services/create . but it throwed me 500 error, can you look back where i made a mistake that would help me a lot

Comment: Your API probably doesn't expect your json to start with a key named json, so remove that. 
{ "Name": "web", "TaskTemplate": { "ContainerSpec": { "Image": "nginx:alpine", "Mounts": [{ "VolumeOptions": { "DriverConfig":{}}}], "User": "33" }, "LogDriver": { "Name": "json-file", "Options": { "max-file": "3", "max-size": "10M" }}}}

Comment: i tried that jack but it didn't solve the issue . below is the error message i am getting : HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Docker/1.12.2 (linux)
Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2016 14:12:12 GMT
Content-Length: 81

Comment: It's pretty much going to be impossible to diagnose that in the context of this question. I'd suggest asking a new question and including what application is running on the server, and the application logs. Probably it can't handle something in the given input